# Comparing DateTimes in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

```
private void ValidateEffectiveDate()
{
    bool ICAdvanced = SessionManager.DisplayUser.IsInRole(PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced);
    if (!ICAdvanced && model.EffectiveDate < DateTime.Now)
    {
         this.CheckAndAddValidation("EffectiveDate",
            "You do not have the advanced permission, so you " + 
            "are unable to value historical indications.");
    }
}
```

If you are NOT ICAdvanced, you should NOT be able to have a date that is in the past, one day before today or earlier. However, you CAN have today or in the future.

Why is this code not reflecting that correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you're going from *now*, rather than *today* for one thing. If "now" is 5pm, but EffectiveDate is midnight today, then currently that's going to add a validation error.

So you *might* want:

```
if (!ICAdvanced && model.EffectiveDate < DateTime.Today)
```

However, you also need to work out how `model.EffectiveDate` is represented. `DateTime` is very unfortunate of its handling of time zones, as a value can be UTC, local or unspecified. I'm not currently clear on how that affects comparisons (if I compare "local midnight" with a "UTC midnight" in a time zone of UTC+5, what should the result be)? I *think* it treats both of them as being local, so it would compare "local midnight" and "UTC midnight" as being the same. Worth thinking about though.

Comment: do you have any follow up on comparing times from different time zones?

Comment: @froeschli: Well DateTime doesn't even have the *concept* of a particular time zone, beyond local/UTC/unspecified. Basically I view the .NET date and time API as somewhat broken, which is why I started Noda Time - but that's not even close to production-ready yet.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was wondering because Robert C. Martin has an entire chapter on comparing dates in Java in his book _Clean_ _Code_. But AFAIR he does not mention time zones either. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the problem is that you are forcing it to be after the current instant, not today or later. It should perhaps be like this instead:

```
private void ValidateEffectiveDate()
{
    bool ICAdvanced = SessionManager.DisplayUser.IsInRole(PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced);
    if (!ICAdvanced && model.EffectiveDate < DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        this.CheckAndAddValidation("EffectiveDate", "You do not have the advanced permission, so you are unable to value historical indications.");
    }
}
```